# .htaccess redirect non-www to www, but within a subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have a wordpress installation in the root of the server. I then have a kohana framework in a sub directory. I want to redirect any urls in the kohana framework from non-www to www.

The url structure for the base of the kohana framework is www.mydomain.com/quotes

I've tried adapting the standard redirect I've used before, but it's not working as expected. It redirects to the www version but it adds index.php at the end (www.mydomain.com/quotes/index.php).

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention I need this to redirect to https as well.

Below is my .htaccess file:

```
# Turn on URL rewriting
RewriteEngine On

# Installation directory
RewriteBase /quotes

# Protect hidden files from being viewed
<Files .*>
Order Deny,Allow
Deny From All
</Files>

# Protect application and system files from being viewed
RewriteRule ^(?:application|modules|system)\b.* index.php/$0 [L]

# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# Rewrite all other URLs to index.php/URL
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT]

# 301 redirect to dubdubdub
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/quotes/$1 [R=301,L]
```

How do I get this working so that the url redirects to **www.mydomain.com/quotes/** and not **www.mydomain.com/quotes/index.php**

Comment: Put your non-www redirect rule at the top of your htaccess and bellow `RewriteEngine on` line

Comment: That didn't work. Still getting index.php included in the url

Comment: Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: Pesky cache...always a nuisance. It's working now. Thanks. If you want to post your solution as an answer I'll be happy to accept it ;)